# Flutter - List<XFile> from url

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to store image from image URL to `List<XFile>`?
I was able to storage image from local asset to `List<XFile>` using this code:

```
final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
   imageFileList!.addAll(selectedImages);
}
```

then I save the image to server, but next time when I want to edit the image that I upload before, I was unable to store data from url to the `List<XFile>`. Any suggestions?

> [UPDATE]

here is my json file example:

```
"gallery": [
   {
       "id": "1",
       "photo": "http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/images/3c94a288a6755c2a.png"
   },
   {
        "id": "2",
        "photo": "http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/images/4eb406695e6d2f4e.png"
    }
],
```

Comment: What format of saved images you are using?

Comment: @fartem i use .png format, please check my question updates. I was add json example.

Comment: How you upload image to the server?

Comment: using base64encode like this:
for (File img in imageFileList!) {
   base64Encode(File(img.path).readAsBytesSync())
}

Comment: And how you are restoring an image from data?